# Regex Expression for Brackets inside Javascript Comma Deliminated

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I am trying to get a regexp to get the following string.

```
[[[455837.99,2896882.36],[455862.44,2896888.35],[455868.79,2896860.14],[455864.3,2896852.78],[455845.76,2896848],[455837.99,2896882.36]]]
```

The desired output is an array that looks like this:

```
455837.99,2896882.36
455862.44,2896888.35
455868.79,2896860.14
```

etc.

I have this:

```
   if (preg_match_all('/\[.*?\]/', $data, $matches))
 {
   print_r($matches[0]); 
 }
```

Which produces:

```
'["cmdlegend"] [16] => ["cmdloc"] [17] => ['Toolbar1'] [18] => ['Toolbar1_Group'] [19] => ['Toolbar1'] [20] => ['Toolbar1'] [21] => ['Toolbar1'] [22] => ['Toolbar1'] [23] => ['Toolbar1'] [24] => ["Map1"] [25] => [{"id":63664,"isSelected":true,"attributes":{"PARCEL_NO":"08009491","SHAPE.FID":63664,"SHAPE_Length":117.084234763352,"SHAPE.AREA":864.2009},"geometry":{"type":"polygon","rings":[[[455837.99,2896882.36] [26] => [455862.44,2896888.35] [27] => [455868.79,2896860.14] [28] => [455864.3,2896852.78] [29] => [455845.76,2896848] [30] => [455837.99,2896882.36] [31] => [455837.99,2896848,455868.79,2896888.35] ) '
```

I only want from after "rings":[["

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like PHP, not JavaScript. Maybe you should edit your tags or explain the role of JS in all this.

Comment: I am scraping a website, and it produces javascript, I was using simple html dom  that seems like it cannot parse javascript, so I settled for preg_match in order to get the parts I need that way.

Comment: I can't understand how to get only that little part, which matches other tags on the source as well. Please don't link me to that post that says don't scrape html with regex :)

Comment: so you want everything between `[[[` and `]]]`, right? Start with `/\[{3}.*\]{3}/`

Comment: This string looks like json, why not to use json functions?

Comment: @pawel, thanks. That will get me there, I can filter out the rest in PHP.

Comment: @georg I think `json_decode` would be the next step after extracting the JSON string from surrounding HTML/JS source code.